# Disable Okular Cache

Tags: kde, okular

I have a problem with `okular` (or it is actually not a problem but irritating).
Because of reasons I sometimes start `okular` from command line (`zsh`) and after I closed `okular` (sometimes after some seconds, not immediately which irritates me) it print something like:

```
schoenix:~$ okular file.pdf  
schoenix:~$ Creating the cache for:  "/home/schoenix/file.pdf"
Already in database?  true
      First update :  QDateTime(2018-01-22 15:14:58.000 CET Qt::TimeSpec(LocalTime))
       Last update :  QDateTime(2018-02-07 14:26:43.000 CET Qt::TimeSpec(LocalTime))
After the adjustment
     Current score :  9.14105
      First update :  QDateTime(2018-01-22 15:14:58.000 CET Qt::TimeSpec(LocalTime))
       Last update :  QDateTime(2018-02-07 14:26:43.000 CET Qt::TimeSpec(LocalTime))
Interval length is  3
         New score :  9.19105
ResourceScoreUpdated: "5ce27654-47a4-4b51-a7fd-f0d865917aff" "okular" "/home/schoenix/file.pdf"
```

After that it stops and I have to kill it via <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, and sometimes it came some seconds later and I already typed a new command and it mixed with this output.

I want either disable the cache (how?) or disable this output.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Had the same issue (openSuse 42.3) and traced it to kactivitymanagerd but found no proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see this with okular on my system (up-to-date Arch Linux, Okular 17.12.1-1). There is no output at all for me. Nevertheless, here are two options.

1. Just close the terminal and open another one.
2. Suppress all output with `okular file.pdf >/dev/null`

If the last is too annoying to type constantly, you could always make an alias. Put the following in `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias okular='okular >/dev/null'
```

Answer (score 1):

Still an issue in openSUSE Leap 15.1.

Manually created `/etc/xdg/QtProject/qtlogging.ini` (path found via `strace okular`) and restarted (killed) `kactivitymanagerd`. Seems to work for me.